# Autocomplete doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've downloaded this [jQuery-Autocomplete Plugin](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) .
The request works fine but there is something wrong in my Code or Response.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> *if (suggestions.length && typeof suggestions[0] === 'string') { ...*

My JS:

```
$('#myInput').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'php/airports.php?get',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        //Do something         
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" />
```

My Request:

```
http://xxx/xxx/xxx/airports.php?get&query=hann
```

My Response:

```
[
  {"name":"Hannover","iata":"HAJ"},
  {"name":"Shannon","iata":"SNN"}
]
```

Comment: Where does that error occur?

Comment: in which line does that error raises?

Comment: @alexP Please include more code ... we don't have enough context to help you at this point.

Comment: I've added the incorrect line to the question. The line is from the plugin.

Comment: I've got it:
The response format was incorrect. suggestions : [{ data : value}] is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need to include the `?get` in your url-- autocomplete should to that for you. You're probably not hitting the url you think you are, and are thus returning `undefined` to autocomplete, which tries to calculate things based on the length of the response.

Comment: I need the "get"-parameter and the request works fine with that.